# Security vulnerabilities of letting users add content to a site's header

Tags: javascript, security, google-analytics

In my application I let registered users create their own personal website, and I want to let them add an analytics code into the sites header. I understand that there is a risk letting them add their own content so I have limited only to let them add a Google Analytic code.

1. What is the worse that could happen if I let them enter their own JavaScript into the header of the website.
2. How can I go about to limit only the Google Analytic code to be added?

Comment: For #1, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting.  Never let an untrusted user cause your site to serve their arbitrary scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Oh let's see... They could redirect users to a phishing or malware site; attempt to set up drive-by-downloads; completely rewrite the entire pages contents and steal sessions, login credentials and other information from the user or otherwise deface the site; install a keylogger into the user's browser whilst they are on your site...
2. Write a check that ensures the ID string provided fits the pattern that all anayltics IDs must follow. Only allow the characters that may appear in an analytics ID. Generate the rest of the surrounding js code yourself. In the comments @yahelc provides the regex `^UA-\d+-\d+$` to validate the UA ID.

Comment: A user figured out how to inject javascript code into a MySpace page several years ago. The fastest worm ever created. http://betanews.com/2005/10/13/cross-site-scripting-worm-hits-myspace/

Answer (score 5):

Don't let them add the whole JavaScript. You add the JavaScript and let them set their Google Analytics ID which you can validate as being in a proper format. That way they can't add any code to your site and you can easily weed out bad values.

Comment: You mean the UA id? Is that enough information to create a Google Analytic code?

Comment: Yep. If you want to let them add functionality you can let them choose which features they want and add the code yourself. An example would be tracking page load speed.

Comment: And please remember to sanitize your inputs. Otherwise they can insert the following id. `UA-XXXX-X'; evil();//`. Make sure they only insert a number in the format of a GA Account number.

Comment: The account id string should match the regex: `^UA-\d+-\d+$`

Comment: I think you meant `\AUA-\d+-\d+\z`.  Otherwise, it's possible to inject a newline and arbitrary javascript.